# Cannot convert value of type '[Double]' to expected argument type 'Double'

Tags: ios, swift

This might be a very stupid question but I can't seem to find an answer.
I have this piece of code which converts an input of numbers into doubles :

```
var array: [Double]! = []
data = try String(contentsOfFile: localFilePath as String,
                      encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)

let myStrings = data.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.newlineCharacterSet())

var trial = myStrings[0].componentsSeparatedByString(",").flatMap{Double($0.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(.whitespaceCharacterSet()))}

array.append(trial)
```

So for example if my file has these numbers `1.2,3.4,5.6` then the output will be `[1.2,3.4,5.6]` and so on.
I get the above error when I try to append my array, what is the right way of casting this? Thank you.

Comment: Tip: in Xcode, do ALT+CLICK on a method/property/variable name, you will see its signature/type. Looks at the flatMap one, and your trial one. You will see something interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is `appendContentsOf`, not `append`.

`flatMap` returns a `[Double]`, and you want to **append the contents of** that array to `array`.

Merely change

```
array.append(trial)
```

to:

```
array.appendContentsOf(trial)
```